# AutoPostBack and HTML encoding

Tags: asp.net

I'm having trouble with HTML characters in a text field and an AutoPostBack.

I have something like the below:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" 
              DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4"
              ForeColor="#333333" DefaultMode="Edit" 
              HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Size="X-Small"
              Width="100%" OnDataBound="FormView1_DataBound">
      <asp:TextBox ID="fooTextBox" runat="server" 
                   Width="100%" Rows="4" TextMode="MultiLine"
                   CssClass="tr4" Text='<%# Bind("foo") %>' AutoPostBack="true"
                   OnTextChanged="ChangedRecord" />
</asp:FormView>
```

Now when a user enters into the textbox something like

> < foo>

it will throw an error 500 due to the HTML characters in the text field.

How can I manage this before it is sent via the AutoPostBack?

Comment: what causing you the error the asp part or the backside

Comment: I believe it to be the AutoPostBack, as adding a HttpUtility.HtmlEncode to the ChangedRecord method (called OnTextChanged) does not encode the HTML characters. It seems the AutoPostBack is called before this ChangedRecord method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *because* of [ValidateRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.validaterequest.aspx) property of Page (Default value is *true*). You can turn off ValidateRequest so you can allow tags,script etc (potentially dangerous values).

If your application target to [.net framework version 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestvalidationmode%28VS.100%29.aspx) then add following section in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Ideally I wouldn't want to retain potentially dangerous characters, but rather encode or remove them before the postback. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use jQuery or JavaScript `escape()` before you submit for data.

Comment: That doesn't work as the postback is called automatically (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx). I would still like this to occur, but would like to escape the content before it is posted back.

Comment: It is better receive tags/text and encode it with `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(fooTextBox);`

Comment: Alright, went with this one as the solution, putting <%@ Page ValidateRequest="false" %> at the top of the page. The TextBox component automatically escapes dangerous content, and this is not presented elsewhere, so this should not be an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to enter html/xml into a textbox the best way of handling it is to **html encode** your input.
`<foo>` will become `&lt;foo&gt;` This will make it safe for the form post. Remember that you need to decode it on after submitting it for use. Use the following link inspect html encoding. http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/Encode.aspx/

Comment: I've tried that, but I need a way of catching the existing input before it's passed through the AutoPostBack to actually encode the input.

Comment: Well then I would suggest a javascript onchange or onblur function in the textbox that looks for html charaters as you type or paste and should replace on the fly with encoded html. This will be extra effort but should catch the input before encoding it.